# How can Skype display targeted ads based on searches?

Tags: google-chrome, search, skype

My girlfriend made a series of very specific product searches yesterday, mostly on Google and Amazon, using Google Chrome. Today, Skype shows an ad banner that matches those searches.

I checked that:

- She did not use Internet Explorer or Bing
- She did not mention any of these searches to any of her Skype contacts

How is this possible? It happens that she uses the same gmail address as a primary email for both Google, Amazon and Skype, but could that really be how she's being tracked?

Comment: Its very common thing. they are collecting user search details. Sometimes selling those informations for other dealers.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible Microsoft (and by extension, Skype) is tracking her through a cookie in whatever browser she's using and then conveying that information to the Skype client upon login.

Comment: It's not just cookies. Various companies take your data and share with 3rd parties. Some of which will specialise in targeted advertising.  I've even seen a demonstration where tracking is possible without cookies based upon the *fingerprint* of a browser and browsing behaviour.

Comment: Can you elaborate? If she's not searching on any Microsoft owned website, where does the cookie come from?